# error when using Alamofire to download an image

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Trying to make a fix in a pre-existing project with Alamofire but I am getting an error.

The code in question is:

```
   Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://www.domain.com/demo-mobile-images/dogs-blue.jpg" ).response { (request, response, data , error) in
       tableViewCell.backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(data: data, scale:1)
    }
```

but I get error:

```
Cannot invoke 'response' with an argument list of type '((_, _, _, _) -> _)'
```

It looks like what I'm trying to call is really standard and I'm not sure what the error msg is telling me. The `_` I thought means unnamed parameters.

How would I download an image via Alamofire?

## edit 1 - here's a screenshot of the error

can Cmd + Click and "Open Image In New Tab" to get full-sized image

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, imageURL).response() {
  (_, _, data, _) in
  let image = UIImage(data: data! as! NSData)
  tableViewCell.backgroundImageView.image = image
}
```

Response need to be called with empty parameters and a completion handler.

Comment: thx, I tried that but got the same error. I had tried that before as it is usually how I call with Alamofire (ok, jsut a few Json requests) but just stumped on this.

Comment: I've included a screenshot of the error (can cotrol + click and Open Image in New Tab to get full size image)

Comment: @timpone I just update my answer to exactly what I normally use, can you give it a try?

Comment: nice - I might have missed the exclamation points previously.

Comment: @timpone I probably missed that too! I am glad it work now, Good luck finishing your app!

Answer (score 0):

What is important in these cases is to cancel the request in progress for the cell, because if not properly canceled, a mistaken image can be shown.

I have developed a small and straightforward CocoaPods library to work with Alamofire and Images. The library just handles the canceling automatically whenever a new request is made for the same image view object.

CocoaPods is a great way of addressing your library dependencies needs. It is easy to install once, and easy to add and update dependencies to your projects.

The library is open source and can be found at https://github.com/gchiacchio/AlamoImage

It has great documentation with examples, so you will be enjoying it in minutes.

I have it working in a couple of project myself, including collection views and scrolling.

Comment: This is still in swift 3 version. Not able to compile the app.